# I have 2 mysql RDS masters and need 1 slave on ec2 machine as their slave. Is it possible to achieve with mariadb running on ec2

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, database-replication, rds

I have 2 mysql RDS masters and need 1 slave on ec2 machine as their slave. Is it possible to achieve this feat with mariadb running on ec2.

should we use change master to or is there any other command to enter 2 master hosts.

Also how do i set only particular databases to get replicated on mariadb and not all.There are mmultiple databases on individual RDS.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be possible if you are using RDS.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible dude. I have set up replication enabled on my ec2 mariadb server.

Only problem is "Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Could not find first log file name in binary log index file'"

it is not able to replicate rds database on replica. For that i have used : SET GLOBAL replicate_ignore_db='mysql';

still it isnt replicating.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved once i upgraded my mariadb from 10.1.to 10.2
then replicat_ignore_db in my.cnf worked.

But now getting different sort of error:

Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails.
It is trying to insert in table2 before table 1. table1 is parent table.

Answer (score 0):

We have achieved this. Posting link of the blog explaining how it is done.

https://medium.com/@ankd99/multisource-replication-from-rds-masters-to-mariadb-on-ec2-bdf87e5dc8c3